# How to show popup in 1 thread?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, multithreading

I have a .NET LinkButton event which takes a lot of time(thousands of Database operations). 
I try to avoid users from clicking somewhere else until my event is finished. So I open a modal popup for this but I can't hide it at the end of my event.

```
protected void ButtonLoadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(),"ex", "showPopup();", true);
        //LOTS OF OPERATIONS
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(),"ex", "hidePopup();", true);
```

The first javascript runs(opens my Loading popup) and the Operations executes in the background but the second javascript does not run. How can I solve this problem? any suggestions

Comment: Are you using partial update panels on the page ?

Comment: Yes, this is actually a UserControl and it is put inside an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand why you are having this problem, you must understand the basics of the HTTP protocol. HTTP is a stateless protocol, which means that once the client (browser) request a page from the server and after the page is delivered by the server. The client and the server forget about each other.

In your code, your trying to accomplish three steps. The first step is performed when the user clicks the LinkButton on the page and a request is sent to the server to perform a particular action. The server in response shows a modal popup and starts the 1000's of database operations. This is where the problem occurs, by the time, the DB operations have completed, the connection between the server and client is over. Therefore when the server tries to execute the third operation, it fails silently.

I would suggest using a UpdateProgress controls to show the user that some action is being performed. This [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx) from msdn will help you understand the UpdateProgress controls.